# Как сделать, чтобы в QComboBox появился столбец из SQLite файла

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, sqlite3, qtsql

Нужно, чтобы в `QComboBox` (переменная '**`passwordS`**') высвечивались все значения в столбце `service` из файла **`db (SQLite)`**.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QToolTip, QComboBox, QLineEdit, QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

# Позже, эти две переменные должны работать за счёт sqlite
Pass = ""
passDat = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "dwdw", "wdwd", "gegr", "fdefegeg", "efefe", "efefe", "efefe"]

class MasterWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Window()

    def Window(self):
        global Pass

        self.setFixedSize(300, 130)
        self.move(300, 300)

        self.setWindowTitle("Master-Pass v0.1")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/ico.png"))

        # Шрифты
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
        QPushButton.setFont(self, QFont("Arial", 10))
        QLineEdit.setFont(self, QFont("Arial", 10))
        QComboBox.setFont(self, QFont("Arial", 10))

        addBtn = QPushButton("Добавить", self)
        addBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        addBtn.setToolTip("Добавить пороль в базу данных")
        addBtn.move(220, 10)

        delBtn = QPushButton("Удалить", self)
        delBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        delBtn.setToolTip("Удалить пороль из базы данных")
        delBtn.move(220, 35)

        quitBtn = QPushButton("Выход", self)
        quitBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        quitBtn.setToolTip("Выход из программы")
        quitBtn.move(10, 100)
        quitBtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        openBtn = QPushButton("Открыть", self)
        openBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        openBtn.setToolTip("Показать <b>выбранный</b> пороль")
        openBtn.move(85, 100)

        # Изменение, если ключ уже есть
        if Pass == "":
            masterPass = QPushButton("Задать мастер-ключ", self)
            masterPass.setFixedSize(140, 23)
            masterPass.setToolTip("<b>У вас не установлен мастер-ключ</b>")
            masterPass.move(10, 10)
        else:
            masterPass = QPushButton("Сменить мастер-ключ", self)
            masterPass.setFixedSize(145, 23)
            masterPass.setToolTip("Сменить мастер-ключ для подтверждения")
            masterPass.move(10, 10)

        # Выбор сервиса
        passwordS = QComboBox(self)
        passwordS.addItems(passDat)
        passwordS.setFixedSize(200, 23)
        passwordS.move(10, 35)

        masterPassInput = QLineEdit(self)
        masterPassInput.setFixedSize(200, 23)
        masterPassInput.setToolTip("Введите мастер-ключ")
        masterPassInput.move(10, 60)

        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    start = MasterWindow()
    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

---

Скрипт для создания БД **`PassData.db`** и таблицы **`passwords`**:

```
import sqlite3

open = sqlite3.connect("PassData.db")
edit = open.cursor()

edit.execute("""CREATE TABLE passwords (service text, password text, dlc text)""")
```

Ну, а дальше вообще не втыкаю, что делать, помогите. 
Нужна помощь только с `QComboBox`, больше ничего.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QToolTip, QComboBox, 
                             QLineEdit, QLabel, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

from PyQt5 import QtSql                                            # +++
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase                               # +++


# Позже, эти две переменные должны работать за счёт sqlite
#Pass = ""
#passDat = ["pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4", "dwdw", "wdwd", 
#           "gegr", "fdefegeg", "efefe", "efefe", "efefe"]

class MasterWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.Pass = ''                                              # +++

        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("PassData.db")
        if not self.db.open():
            print("Cannot establish a database connection")
            return False   

        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("passwords")  #("phone_number_type")
        self.model.select()        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.Window()

    def Window(self):
#        global Pass

        self.setFixedSize(300, 130)
        self.move(300, 300)

        self.setWindowTitle("Master-Pass v0.1")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("img/ico.png"))

        # Шрифты
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
        QPushButton.setFont(self, QFont("Arial", 10))
        QLineEdit.setFont(self, QFont("Arial", 10))
        QComboBox.setFont(self, QFont("Arial", 10))

        addBtn = QPushButton("Добавить", self)
        addBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        addBtn.setToolTip("Добавить пороль в базу данных")
        addBtn.move(220, 10)

        delBtn = QPushButton("Удалить", self)
        delBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        delBtn.setToolTip("Удалить пороль из базы данных")
        delBtn.move(220, 35)

        quitBtn = QPushButton("Выход", self)
        quitBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        quitBtn.setToolTip("Выход из программы")
        quitBtn.move(10, 100)
        quitBtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        openBtn = QPushButton("Открыть", self)
        openBtn.setFixedSize(70, 23)
        openBtn.setToolTip("Показать <b>выбранный</b> пороль")
        openBtn.move(85, 100)

        # Изменение, если ключ уже есть
#        if Pass == "":
        if self.Pass == "":
            masterPass = QPushButton("Задать мастер-ключ", self)
            masterPass.setFixedSize(140, 23)
            masterPass.setToolTip("<b>У вас не установлен мастер-ключ</b>")
            masterPass.move(10, 10)
        else:
            masterPass = QPushButton("Сменить мастер-ключ", self)
            masterPass.setFixedSize(145, 23)
            masterPass.setToolTip("Сменить мастер-ключ для подтверждения")
            masterPass.move(10, 10)

        # Выбор сервиса
        passwordS = QComboBox(self)
# -       passwordS.addItems(passDat)
        passwordS.setFixedSize(200, 23)
        passwordS.move(10, 35)

        # Перед установкой колонки модели установите модель.
        passwordS.setModel(self.model)                                # <----- +++
        passwordS.setModelColumn(self.model.fieldIndex("service"))    # <----- +++

        masterPassInput = QLineEdit(self)
        masterPassInput.setFixedSize(200, 23)
        masterPassInput.setToolTip("Введите мастер-ключ")
        masterPassInput.move(10, 60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    start = MasterWindow()
    start.show()
    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Глобальные переменные - это зло.

Answer (score 1):

нужно парсить базу, взяв только значения столбца service, дальше для каждого найденного надо будет добавить в `QComboBox` это значение:

```
self.passwordS.addItem()
```